# NSURLSession loading quickly, but UI changes take too long

Tags: php, ios, objective-c

I'm making an app that uses `NSURLSession` to get data from a "php backend". I used `NSLog` to check how much time it takes to get the data, and the data comes in almost instantly. However, once I hook it up to change the text of a `UILabel`, it takes more than a few seconds for the text to change. Isn't `NSURLSession` supposed to relegate fetching to background threads so UI interactions are faster?
Also, is there any way to speed this up? Here's my `viewController` code:-

```
    //
//  hoursViewController.m
//  NSS IITD
//
//  Created by Robin Malhotra on 22/05/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Robin's code kitchen. All rights reserved.
//

#import "hoursViewController.h"

@interface hoursViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *hoursLabel;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSArray *dataArray;
@end


@implementation hoursViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
- (IBAction)checkHours:(id)sender
{
    NSString *URL=@"http://www.nssiitd.in/nsshours/teststudent.php?entry_no=2012TT10951";
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
            completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                NSURLResponse *response,
                                NSError *error){
                NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                NSLog(@"%@",dataString);
                self.dataArray=[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

                for (NSString *string in self.dataArray) {

                    NSLog(@"%@",string);

                }

                NSLog(@"lasdt valiuse is %@",[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:2]);
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hours" message:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:4] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                [self.hoursLabel setText:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:4]];

            }] resume];


}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];




    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

And "[Here's](https://github.com/codeofRobin/NSS-IITD)" the entire project on "gitHub".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try dispatching the UI code in the main thread:

```
[[session dataTaskWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:URL]
        completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                            NSURLResponse *response,
                            NSError *error){
            NSString *dataString=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"%@",dataString);
            self.dataArray=[dataString componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

            for (NSString *string in self.dataArray) {

                NSLog(@"%@",string);

            }

            NSLog(@"lasdt valiuse is %@",[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:2]);

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Hours" message:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:4] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"okay" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                [alert show];
                [self.hoursLabel setText:[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:4]];
            });

        }] resume];
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Unfortunately, I can't vote you up because I don't have the reputation for it

Comment: @RobinThuranMalhotra If this solved your problem (it should) be sure to accept the answer so others don't scratch their heads over it.

Comment: @Pablo some explanation of the change noting that UI modifications can only be made by the main thread would be helpful as well :)